# Generate a two dimensional array in Javascript

Tags: javascript, arrays, d3.js

I want to generate an array like this:

```
layers = [
     [{"x1":0,"y":0.55,"y0":0},{"x1":1,"y":0.804,"y0":0}],
     [{"x2":0, "y":0.189,"y0":0.553},{"x2":1,"y":0.189,"y0":0.804}]
    ];
```

To generate this in JavaScript, I go through the whole CSV dataset and created a two dimensional array and push each object into it:

```
var layers = new Array(2);
    layers[0] = new Array();
    layers[1] = new Array();

d3.csv("data.csv", function(error, data) {
  if (error) throw error;

  var ageNames = ["x1", "x2"];

  data.forEach(function(d) {
    var y0 = 0;
    d.ages = ageNames.map(function(name) { return {name: d.x, y0: y0, y: y0 += +d[name]}; });
    layers[0].push(d.ages[0]);
    layers[1].push(d.ages[1]);
    });
  });
```

But it seems like the array structure isn't identical to the one I want originally. Any solutions?

Comment: can u add the structure that u have currently?

Comment: Using `name` as name in an object literal will place the value at `object["name"]` rather than `object[name]`. You can only use the contents of variables as names with the bracket syntax, not when constructing objects.

Comment: @Siguza Good catch! It took me a while to understand what you were after, but you are right. Partially, though ;-) You could use [computed property names](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Object_initializer#Computed_property_names) in an object initializer. In this example it would be `{ [name]: d.x }` This will [leave out](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Object_initializer#Browser_compatibility) IE, though.

Comment: @altocumulus Huh, didn't know that was a thing. Well, you learn something new every day :)

Comment: Hey, guys, just a side note not related to the question: try to avoid using "name" as a name for variables or properties. "Name" is a name of JavaScript built-in properties/methods, and can hold only strings and any object, including arrays, is coerced to primitive type. For instance, try this: `var name = ["a", "b", "c"];`. If you console.log it, you'll get a string: `console.log(name);//returns "a,b,c"`.